# Complete removal of Oracle Developer Suite 10g from Windows XP (SP3)

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall

Does anyone know how to remove/uninstall Oracle Developer Suite 10g from Windows XP (SP3) ? It's not appearing in the "Add or Remove Programs" list and it doesn't have a built-in uninstaller.

I've googled around for how to do this, and basically, everyone says to run the Oracle Universal Installer shipped with every Oracle product. I've tried to run it from the Oracle Developer Suite 10g installation kit, but it crashes. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=397953 it's an old "you have spaces in your pathname" issue. You have to move the Oracle Universal Installer folder to an 8 characters, no-space folder like `C:\Oracle`

Answer (score 0):

go into your Oracle home directory,

something like

`C:\Oracle\Middleware\utils\uninstall` and run `uninstall.exe` or `uninstall.cmd` , you might get a more detailed error message.